# Trying to Convert C++ to Java

Tags: java, c++

I am trying to convert source code from C++ to Java and i have done all of it except from one method that seems to be returning the wrong type and im not sure how i should format it correctly...

this is the C++ code i want to convert

```
int find( int x )
{
    return f[x]==x ? x : f[x]=find(f[x]);
}
```

and this is what i thought it would be in Java but it wont work as it says cannot convert int to boolean but how would i correctly convert?

```
public static int find(int x)
{
    return f[x] == x != 0 ? x : f[x] = find(f[x]);
}
```

Comment: Why you change the return , it would work like normal no need of additional changes

Comment: You don't need `!= 0`, because `f[x]==x` is already a boolean.

Comment: Post full error messages and complete code.

Answer (score 3):

`f[x] == x != 0 ? x : f[x] = find(f[x])` means compare `f[x]` with `x != 0 ? x : f[x] = find(f[x])`, then this produces a `boolean` while the return type is `int`.

You don't have to change the original expression, let it as is, it will work correctly: `f[x] == x ? x : (f[x] = find(f[x]))`

Comment: I keep getting this error though.  "incomparable types: boolean and int.
unexpected type
required: variable
found: value"

Answer (score 1):

The result of `f[x] == x` is already a boolean. All you need do is

```
public static int find(int x) {
    return f[x] == x ? x : (f[x] = find(f[x]));
}
```

You need an extra () around the assignment as it has lower precedence.

Comment: With this one i get the error `unexpected type required: variable found: value.  Also that it will recur infinitely`

Comment: @ElliottSmelliott Good point, I have corrected and checked it.